# File not found error while testing python impyla

Tags: python-2.7, pytest, impyla

I am trying to set up a connection between python and impala. Based on the instructions [here](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla) I am trying to set up impyla.

I am on a vagrant ubuntu/xenial64 box with python 2.7.12. After reading about [some issues with the latest thrift](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/pull/246) I downgraded to the specified version. After pip installing and setting up the environment variables, I am trying to run the test but it is failing with the file not found error, as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala$ py.test --connect impyla
======================================== test session starts ========================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-2.8.7, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala, inifile:

=================================== no tests ran in 0.00 seconds ====================================
ERROR: file not found: impyla
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impala$
```

I think I am missing out on something very fundamental here. I have no previous experience with python tests. I would like to stick with python 2.7 because of some other dependencies.

PS:

1. Please note the latest version provided in the [repo readme](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla#installation) is 0.13.1 but with my `pip install impyla` it came out to be 0.14.0.
2. I am running the test from my site-package/impala directory as the readme says to be in the directory where impyla is.
3. There is no mention of any inifile in the readme (as far as I could see.)

**EDIT 1:**

When I run it from site-package directory without `--connect` I get the same error. But with the argument, it says that the argument is unrecognizable. The output is as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ py.test --connect impyla
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --connect
  inifile: None
  rootdir: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages$
```

Any help on how to troubleshoot this would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just did it. Same status.